# Conext menu behaviour change in SSMS 18.0/18.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using the new SSMS 18.0 or 18.1 and one thing extremely annoys me -

Upon pressing right click, the context menu is open.

I used to press the "up arrow"+"Return key" to pick the Refresh option.

The circularity isn't working anymore.

Is there anyway to change it?

Thanks!

[image: SSMS screen shot]

Comment: I just checked it, it is working for me with all default settings. SSMS 18.0

Comment: I just checked it, it is working for me with all default settings. SSMS 18.1.

Comment: I don't know what to say. 
I'm installing 17.9 again, to see how it's in there.

Comment: It does work for me on 17.9. On 18.0/18.1 it doesn't. What settings controls this ?

Comment: You mean "Down Arrow" to highlight refresh menu and then hit "enter"? If yes, that works for me in 18.1.

Comment: "Up arrow" once instead of multiple hits on "down arrow".

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot reproduce this problem (i.e. I can right-click on any item in Object Explorer and press <kbd>⇧</kbd> once to get to the bottom of the menu in SSMS 18.0 RTM), if the goal is to reduce the number of times you press a key, then I will suggest abandoning the desired approach (2 keys pressed: <kbd>⇧</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter ↲</kbd>) in favor of simply doing a left-click and then pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> once (i.e. "Refresh"), thereby saving one key-press every time 😺.

Comment: Thanks, but REFRESH is just one scenario that I use, also, when you right click a database and want to pick PROPERTIES, I use the same method, which doesn't work in 18.0/18.1